# Fit model of specific form

Tags: r, regression

Seems like it should be an easy procedure, but I haven't been able to find the answer after some searching through the help databases for ?lm, ?glm, ?loglin, etc.

Given the dataset

```
    Y   X
1   4.040000    0.8247096
2   3.170000    0.7896353
3   4.570000    0.8480331
4   1.460000    0.7236442
5   2.920000    0.8056733
6   4.640000    0.8468943
7   4.400000    0.6950719
8   3.570000    0.6297521
9   4.560000    0.6944195
10  1.760000    0.5485687
11  2.580000    0.6166014
12  4.470000    0.6948886
13  0.600000    0.2951873
14  0.360000    0.3001486
15  2.910000    0.7775315
16  0.580000    0.5239421
17  2.690000    0.7735998
18  2.080000    0.7224670
19  0.450000    0.3042284
20  3.050000    0.8391136
...
```

I would like to fit several models of specific forms to this data, for example:

```
Y = a*(b^X)+c
Y = a*(X^b)+c
```

Is there a simple way to solve for the best fit coefficients a, b, and c given a user-defined functional form? And, while I'm at it, return a R2 or some other metric to determine which is the best fit?

Thanks!

-sam

Comment: I think you are looking for `nls` which is non-linear least squares models; that is you specify functional form to fit to.

Comment: although note that R^2 is dicey at best for non-linear least squares fit -- although it *might* be OK for comparing models with equal numbers of parameters.

Comment: Great- thanks for the tips. I will try nls, and maybe another metric of fit (e.g. RMSE).

Comment: If the `c` terms were not there, you could take the logarithm of both sides and end up with models of the form `log(Y) = log(a) + log(b)*X` and `log(Y) = log(a) + b*log(X)`, and then `lm()` would work on this model just fine. It's the `c` term that makes non-linear fitting methods necessary.